# Issue with hover not filling height of navbar

Tags: html, css

I'm having a hard time getting the background-color to go to the top of the navbar when hovered over. As of now it only highlights a little more than the text. Is there something simple I'm missing? I put a jsfiddle below to help show it.

HTML

```
<nav>
   <ul>
      <li><h1><a id="nav_logo" href="/index.php">This is a Test</a></h1></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="/pages/about.php">About</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">5</a></li>         
   </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav ul{
   list-style: none; 
   background-color: #333;  
   padding: 0.8125rem;
}

nav li{
   display: inline-block;
}

nav a{
   text-decoration: none; 
   color: white;  


}

#nav_logo{
   color:#FEBC11;
   background-color: #333;  
}

.nav_link{
   padding-left: 2rem;
}

nav li a:hover{
   background-color: black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mhLjav1a/3/

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve or elaborate more?

Comment: oops forgot to do so. This is just a jfiddle I found: http://jsfiddle.net/t5QNq/1/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This happened because you gave `padding-left` to `.nav_link` and the background take the padding area as a part of element. 
you can change that by many ways :

1- you can change the `padding-left` to `margin-left`

2- you can use `background-clip:content-box` which will make the `background` ignoring the `padding`

```
background-clip: content-box;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mhLjav1a/6/

Comment: Wow...I knew I should have had coffee this morning. Thank you :) I'm not sure who answered first...but I'm assuming you did since yours shows up first. I'll accept in 4 minutes (As it wont let me before then lol )

Comment: @Ahmed Salama, Good answer. Actually I'm giving a proper answer to this question. In meanwhile you had replied.

Answer (score 1):

```css
nav ul{
    list-style: none; 
    background-color: #333;  
    padding: 0 25px;
    margin: 0;
}

nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.logo {
    padding: 0;
}

nav li:hover{
    background-color: black;
}

nav ul li h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

nav a{
    text-decoration: none; 
    color: white;  
}

#nav_logo{
    color:#FEBC11;
    background-color: #333;  
}

.nav_link{
    margin: auto 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="logo"><h1><a id="nav_logo" href="/index.php">This is a Test</a></h1></li>
        <li><a class="nav_link" href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav_link" href="/pages/about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav_link" href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a class="nav_link" href="pages/contact.php">5</a></li>         
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:  https://jsfiddle.net/mhLjav1a/5/

the problem was about **padding**.

```
.nav_link{
   padding-left: 2rem;
}
```

should be,

```
.nav_link{
   margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understood you wanted to make the `<li>`'s height match the size of the nav. If that is what u want to archive u just need to change the following:

```
nav li{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

to

```
nav li{
   display: table-cell;
   text-align: center;
}
```

and you should add a padding to both sides of the `<li>`'s to make the hover effect look nicer.

```
.nav_link{
  padding: 1rem; // this was padding-left: 2rem; before
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mhLjav1a/10/